# Hide with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like this div to slide up to be hidden and I can figure out how to do that. The way it is set up now is when I click on `#aboutclick` and `#contactclick` then `.thumb` just disapears. I would like for it to slide up and disappear.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".thumb").hide();
  $("#aboutclick, #contactclick").show();
  $("#aboutclick, #contactclick").click(function(){
    $(".thumb").hide();
  });
});
```

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Final/UITabs15.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".thumb").hide();
    $("#aboutclick, #contactclick").show();
    $("#aboutclick, #contactclick").click(function () {
        $(".thumb").hide(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats just what I need. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

use jQuery's [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) function for that. It also takes time.

The name of this function exactly describes what you want to do, to slide up the object, and to hide it (because its height would become zero). There is also another function called [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) which does the opposite, and matches this animation. Also, another function named [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) also might become more handy, when you already don't know that current state of your object, and only want to toggle it.

Answer (score 0):

you could animate for this feature. like this,

```
$(".thumb").animate({height:0,opacity:0},1000,function(){$(".thumb").hide()})
```

Answer (score -2):

Use .toggle() and then .hide();

Comment: I dont want it to toggle. Just hide.

Comment: You can hide it after it has been toggled which has that similar effect. I would do that instead of having to import Jquery UI unless you already have.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 

 
          $(".thumb").hide();
 
          $("#aboutclick, #contactclick").show();
 

 
      $("#aboutclick, #contactclick").click(function(){
 
      $(".thumb").toggle(); .hide();
 
      });
 

 
  });